# Creating all.css and all.js file for WordPress template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have designed a **WordPress** theme for myself. Due to the large number of codes, I have divided the `style` and `script` files into several files.

I have introduced all these files to my template using the following code that I have placed in the **function** file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'files_assets' );

function files_assets() {
    
// Introducing CSS files
  wp_enqueue_style( 'Bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.0.0' );


// Introducing JS files
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery3.4.1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.4.1', true );

}
```

The total number of my style and script files is **61 files** and introducing all of them to the template through the above code is very difficult.

Is there a way that I can link all my style files there by creating the `all.css` file and introduce only this file to my template?

And do the same thing with `script` files through `all.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use build tool like `gulp` or `webpack` to create js and css bundles. Here is sample config for `gulpfile.js`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/css/*.css')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(concat('all.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/env']
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./src/css/*.css', gulp.series('styles'));
  gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('styles', 'scripts', 'watch'));
```

Comment: Hello. That is, if I create a file named gulpfile.js and put your code in it. There is no need to introduce files through the previous code in the function?

Comment: I want to introduce only the JS and CSS folder that I wrote myself.

Comment: This Gulp config just joins all the files in `src/js` and `src/css`. Put the files which you want to process there. You still have to include the bundles  `dist/all.js` and `dist/all.css` in wordpess using `wp_enqueue_style`  and  `wp_enqueue_script`